# Двусторонняя очередь.(Дек)

Tags: c++, структуры-данных, data-structures

Изучаю структуры данных и попалась мне статья под названием [Deque Data Structure](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/deque).
В данной статье приложена реализация дека и теория.
Я ,в основном ,пишу на плюсах и в не понятен один момент, а именно функция getRear();

```
int Deque::getRear() {
  if (isEmpty() || rear < 0) {
    cout << " Deque is Empty"<< endl;
    return -1;
  }
  return *(arr+rear);
}
```

И в чем же, собственно, вопрос!?
**1.Не понимаю почему в данной функции при проверке на пустоту, приписывается rear<0.Можно ли без него?**
В принципе, приблизительно ,я понимаю почему так, но если посмотреть с другой стороны,  **почему бы не приписать в конструкторе сразу rear=-1,а не 0?**
Могу еще сослаться на функцию DeleteRear();,где при удалении последнего элемента,rear=-1 и front=-1.
Но я путаюсь, порой, в своих суждениях, лучше послушать мнения других.

Comment: Вопрос `|| rear < 0` невыполним, так как если он не пустой, то индекс `rear` всегда `>=0`. Это часто встречается, как избыток контроля. Флаг пустоты играет только проверка индекса `front == -1`. Значение `rear` может быть неопределено.

Comment: @AlexGlebe а почему там нельзя бы поставить &&,а не | |  ? И я правильно понимаю,что то,что в конструкторе это всего лишь начальные данные,т.е обязательно rear=0?

Comment: Если он пустой, то в алгоритме не важно значение индекса `rear`. По-этому в `||` пропускается второй вопрос `rear < 0` компилятором. В программе где-то ставят 0 где-то -1. Это уже не важно.

Comment: @AlexGlebe давайте подытожим. Если он пустой, то в алгоритме не важно значение индекса rear.Но разве может быть так,что isEmpty не сработал,а rear<0,по моему нет.Поэтому можем ли мы || rear < 0 убрать?     P.S.Можете добавить ответ на  мой вопрос,я его лайкну.

Comment: imho в работе с кольцевым буфером (в статье *the circular array*) более естественно хранить индекс начала и количество (и работать с unsigned, т.о. использовать арифметику по модулю 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Не понимаю почему в данной функции при проверке на пустоту, приписывается `rear<0`.Можно ли без него?

Вопрос `|| rear < 0` невыполним, так как если он не пустой, то индекс rear всегда `>=0`. Это часто встречается, как избыток контроля. Значение `rear == -1` встречается только в состоянии пустой очереди. То-есть спокойно можно удалить эту проверку, так как она не изменит логику.

```
if (isEmpty() || rear < 0)
 // v
if (isEmpty())
```

> почему бы не приписать в конструкторе сразу `rear=-1`,а не `0`?

Флаг пустоты играет только проверка индекса `front == -1`. Значение `rear` может быть неопределено. И в конструкторе прописали значение `rear = 0` просто-так. Это присвоение не меняет логику программы.

Как сказал [avp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/232/avp), неудачно выбран комплект переменных. Так как пустую очередь невозможно определить с индексами из области `[0 .. size-1]`. Придумали первому индексу ключевое значение **-1**, что не очень сказывается на читаемость и исполняемость программы.

Удобнее было-бы использовать индекс первого и количество. Проверка на пустоту была-бы `count == 0`, а индекс последней записи могла бы быть вычислена так : `rear = (front + count - 1) % size ;`